# Check content extension type before displaying with EJS

Tags: javascript, express, ejs

I am passing content to my EJS template that can either be a png or an mp4 file. My content is a physical path to a file (eg public/assets/file.png)

I'm trying to implement something like this:

```
if (content === image) {

<div> show image <%- content %> </div>

} else {

<div> show video <%- content %></div>
```

How can I achieve this? Any help is appreciated

Ian

Comment: let file1 = "file.png";
let file2 = "file2.mp4";

if(file1.includes(".png")){
  console.log("image");
} else if(file1.includes(".mp4")){
  console.log("video");
}

Comment: @sonEtLumiere That worked! Thank you very much sir :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
A pleasure
```

```js
let file1 = "file.png"; 
let file2 = "file2.mp4"; 

if(file1.includes(".png")){ 
  console.log("image");
} else if(file1.includes(".mp4")){ 
  console.log("video"); 
}
```